# Using $httpBackend to Make Synchronous Calls?

Tags: angularjs, http, asynchronous

We are using a 3rd part i18n module for translations in my app. Specifically https://github.com/doshprompt/angular-localization

#### Problem

The issue we are having is that the `locale` service is needed before it can possibly be loaded. If it is needed in a state we can resolve `locale` on the state resolve but if a script has to run before any state is even requested there is a timing conflict.

In this example I'm trying to load a service that needs `locale` before `locale` is loaded or could possibly have enough time to load.

#### Example

```
angular.module('config', []).service('myService', ['ngLocalization', function(locale) {
    return {
        foo: locale.getString('bar')
    }
}]);

angular.module('app', ['config']).run(['myService', function(myService) {
    /// ... do stuff ...
}]);
```

#### I'm anti-mess

This may seem simple- just add `locale.ready('common').then(function() {});` to the service. And that's something we **COULD** do.. **EVERYWHERE** (there are a lot of places). But we don't want to add this confusing mess to our code that is unstable. And we don't want to get into the habit of having every service, controller, directive, etc etc. checking that all the possible dependencies and their resources are loaded independently.

#### $httpBackend Solution?

$httpBackend is for unit testing but can it be used- or is there another service to use- to set the respond to an http request? And if there is already a response is it then synchronous? Then when the config module loads it makes a `ready` request for all needed lang files which get applied immediately and the timing conflicts will go away.

Thoughts?

Comment: Angular http does not have an synchronous request option right now: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/2391